# SUM(myfield): Arithmetic Overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1

```
SELECT 
    VEN.EAN11ZUC AS EAN
    , SUM(DET.NbMag) --<< when this line is commented, no error!!!
FROM ODS_Vente VEN
inner join ODS_DetentionCentraleArticle DET
    on VEN.EAN11ZUC = DET.EANZUC 
group by VEN.EAN11ZUC
```

Actual output:

> "Msg 8115, Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type
>   numeric"

Comment: What's the precision and scale of `DET.NbMag`?  How many records (approximately) are being summed?

Comment: The error message is quite obvious. So what is the question?

Comment: NBMag is an INT, there are a lot.... of records... (I did a COUNT(*), in 5 minutes I still had no answer...)

Comment: @juergend, special for you: "How can I fix it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the sum cannot fit in the same numeric precision/scale as the source field.  You can try casting the original values to the largest possible precision:

```
SELECT 
    VEN.EAN11ZUC AS EAN
    , SUM(CAST DET.NbMag AS NUMERIC(38,{# of decimals you want to support}) ) 
FROM ODS_Vente VEN
inner join ODS_DetentionCentraleArticle DET
    on VEN.EAN11ZUC = DET.EANZUC 
group by VEN.EAN11ZUC
```